# How can I customize view pager in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-custom-view, viewpagerindicator

I am new to view pager in android. I want to make my view pager like this.
[image]

In this my problem is to making the circles with the number showing. How can I achieve this in android.

I have tried the view pager customizations methods but I didn't succeed. Please tell me how can I achieve this type thing in android.

Answer (score 2):

I have written true `ViewPager` indicators similar to `PagerTabStrip` which are embedded in the `ViewPager` and they are a pain.

This indicator looks like it might be separate from the `ViewPager` anyway, so here is an easier way to do this sort of thing:

- Make a custom widget that extends `LinearLayout`.  This will be a horizontal layout.  Have it also implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.
- In the setup of this widget, you add `ImageView`s to the `LinearLayout` with the drawable set to the circle of your choice.  Use `ViewPager.getAdapter().getCount()` for the number of circles to add.
- in the `onPageSelected()` method, use the position argument as the index to `LinearLayout.getChildAt()` to get the `ImageView` that represents that selected page.  Set the drawable to the image that represents your selected page.  Don't forget to reset the `ImageView` that was previously selected!
- Call `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()` with your widget.

Now if you also want to put a number in there, the views you add to the `LinearLayout` will need to have a `TextView` as well.  You'll also need to get the data to go into the `TextView`, perhaps from a custom method on the `PagerAdapter`.

Also, I'll bet the app you are referencing has an animation showing the bubble expanding.

I'll try to post some code later.